# Which Stack Exchange site should I use for a Unix tool like rsync?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a few questions related to [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/). Some searching has revealed that there are questions related to the tool on at least 4 Stack Exchange sites:

- Stack Overflow
- Super User
- Server Fault
- Unix & Linux

Any suggestions on how I should decide which site to put my questions on?

Comment: SuperUser might be a good starting point.

Comment: It probably depends on the question itself.  You can read the help center for each and figure it out though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit more in depth version of what Oded posted:

- If you're asking a question about using rsync in the sense of running it from the command line, running it from Xwindows, or about specific features that are parts of the command line interface, ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

  > Is there a way using rsync to transfer a file to a SFTP server?
  >
  > How do you avoid filename changes when running rsync on OS X?
- If you're asking a question about installing or managing rsync on a server, particularly that would require some understanding of general server administration to answer, ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com).

  > What ports need to be opened on a Linux server running rsync?
  >
  > I am running rsync on a Windows Server 2008 box, but users cannot log in.
- If you're asking a question about interfacing with rsync programmatically, particularly about its API or other features that would primarily be answered by another programmer, ask on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com).

  > How do I connect to rsync using PHP?
  >
  > How can I write a shell script to rsync all of the files in a directory to another location?

Thinking about *who* would best answer your question is really the best guidance - if only a programmer could answer it, ask on SO.  If only a server admin could answer your question, ask on SF.  If it requires neither specific knowledge, then it's probably best on SU.

Comment: Mostly right... although the last example is a single command and therefore not really a scripting question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, I don't know rsync :) But technically if you wanted to write a shell script to do it...

Answer (score 5):

That entirely depends on the type of questions...

- If you are asking about programming using rsync, use Stack Overflow (that is if you have code, a script for instance, that you can post)
- If the problem is a system administration one (say about opening ports in a firewall), Server Fault should be the place
- Super User is for general software usage questions

Each of the communities has a tour page (`<site address>/tour`) and a help center with a "what's on topic" article. These give you a good idea about, well..., what's on-topic for each of the given sites.

Note that some types of questions don't belong anywhere on the network.

Comment: And all of them could probably fit on Unix.SE